# x:Bind doesn't work on ActualWidth property (broken RegisterPropertyChangedCallback )

Tags: uwp

I am developing a UWP app where I am stuck with RegisterPropertyChangedCallback not working on ActualWidth property. I filed a bug report but I don't expect it to be addressed soon. I need a workaround to make my x:Bind bindings work on ActualWidth property. Any advise will be much appreciated.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
      this.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(Page.ActualWidthProperty, DependencyPropertyChanged_Page_ActualWidth);
}

public void DependencyPropertyChanged_Page_ActualWidth(global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject sender, global::Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyProperty prop) {
  // Doesn't get called
}
```

XAML

```
    <TextBlock x:Name="text" Text="{x:Bind text.ActualWidth, Mode=OneWay}"/> <!-- always shows zero -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActualWidth and ActualHeght are not bindable in UWP (wonder what was the reason behind this decision). WindowsCommunityToolkit has a solution for this (a bit clunky). Check https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/main/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/Extensions/FrameworkElement/FrameworkElementExtensions.ActualSize.cs